# Detection of four corners of a document under different circumstances

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I have tried 2 methodologies as follows:-

1. conversion of image to Mat
2. apply gaussian blur
3. then canny edge detection
4. find contours

The problem with this method is:

1. too many contours are detected
2. mostly open contours
3. doesn't detect what I want to detect

Then I changed my approach and tried adaptive thresholding after gaussian blur/median blur and it is much better and I am able to detect the corners in 50% cases

The current problem I am facing is that the page detection requires contrasting and plain background without any reflections. I think it's too idealistic for real world use.

This is where I would like some help. Even a direction towards the solution is highly appreciated especially in java. Thanks in anticipation
[image]
works absolutely fine with a significant contrasting background like this

[image]

Detected 4 corners
[image]
This picture gives troubles because the background isn't exactly the most contrasting
[image]

Initial largest contour found

**Update:** median blur did not help much so I traced the cause and found that the page boundary was detected in bits and pieces and not a single contour so it detected the biggest contour as a part of the page boundary Therefore performed some morphological operations to close relatively small gaps and the resultant largest contour is definitely improved but its its not optimum. Any ideas how I can improve the big gaps?
[image]

morphed original picture

[image]

largest contour found in the morphed image

PS morphing the image in ideal scenarios has led to detection of false contour boundaries. Any condition which can be checked before morphing an image is also a bonus. Thank you

Comment: If your page color is always white, then you may try color segmentation as well. `inRange` method can be used in that case.

Comment: @ZdaR Nope. Colours can vary because I also want to scan ID cards which may have variable colour background

Comment: If your goal is to scan ID cards, you can try to find not 4 corners, but BoundingRect - it always closed. Than you can filter founded BoundingRects by area and get biggest of its.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Primary function is to scan documents ( may be ID card or any page/s).  BoundingRect works if the orientation is ideal. It will provide obscure points. Plus it is also dependent on detecting the largest contour which is where I am stuck, I always end up with discontinuous contours and the BoundingRect will just draw a rect around a line/contour

Comment: "BoundingRect works if the orientation is ideal." - seems no: BoundingRect works fine every time, not only for ideal orientation - it's rotated rect.

Comment: have you found any solutions

Answer (score 1):

You can pick a single contour by using one or both of:

- Use `BoundingRect` and `ContourArea` to evaluate the [squareness of each contour](http://frc-pdr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vision/contours.html#solidity). `boundingRect()` returns orthogonal rects., to handle arbitrary rotation better use `minAreaRect()` which returns optimally rotated ones.
- Use `Cv.ApproxPoly` iteratively to reduce to a 4 sided shape

  ```
          var approxIter = 1;
          while (true)
          {
              var approxCurve = Cv.ApproxPoly(largestContour, 0, null, ApproxPolyMethod.DP, approxIter, true);
              var approxCurvePointsTmp = new[] { approxCurve.Select(p => new CvPoint2D32f((int)p.Value.X, (int)p.Value.Y)).ToArray() }.ToArray();
              if (approxCurvePointsTmp[0].Length == 4)
              {
                  corners = approxCurvePointsTmp[0];
                  break;
              }
              else if (approxCurvePointsTmp[0].Length < 4) throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to decimate corner points");
              approxIter++;
          }
  ```

However neither of these will help if the contour detection gives you two separate contours due to noise / contrast.

I think it would be possible to use the hough line transformation to help detect cases where a line has been split into two contours.

If so the search could be repeated for all combinations of joined contours to see if a bigger / more rectangular match is found.

Comment: I am unable to use HoughLine method properly. It gives way too many lines for 80 threshold and the worst part being none of the lines seem to be the page boundary. Can you provide resources to implement it in java preferably?

Comment: I don't have any Java examples unfortunately.

Comment: I don't mind other languages as long as it offers something concrete for a solution to my problem

Comment: I've used the squareness/approximation method followed by sub pixel corner refinement and inverse perspective before - it works but is dependent on the threshold results. I didn't solve the problem of holes in contours.

Comment: Hey Peter, I was able to figure out how to detect a continuous and reliable contour in the image. Now I think the best approach to find the corners of the contour is to use Hough line because sometimes the contour detect is an irregular figure due to the blur used and hough lines will always help detect the proper rectangle. Now, the problem is that the lines which are detected are too many and too un-accurate. A little guidance or some resources are much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like this should be an update/new question. As a final note I revisited my attempt at combining hough and contour extraction. I used the saturation channel for edge detection, then `HoughLines2` in probabilistic mode. I was able to get a bunch of line segments on the perimeter of the second image but they'd need further processing to make a single rectangle or polyline.

Answer (score 1):

If you use methods like that:

```
public static RotatedRect getBestRectByArea(List<RotatedRect> boundingRects) {
    RotatedRect bestRect = null;

    if (boundingRects.size() >= 1) {
        RotatedRect boundingRect;
        Point[] vertices = new Point[4];
        Rect rect;
        double maxArea;
        int ixMaxArea = 0;

        // find best rect by area
        boundingRect = boundingRects.get(ixMaxArea);
        boundingRect.points(vertices);
        rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(new MatOfPoint(vertices));
        maxArea = rect.area();

        for (int ix = 1; ix < boundingRects.size(); ix++) {
            boundingRect = boundingRects.get(ix);
            boundingRect.points(vertices);
            rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(new MatOfPoint(vertices));

            if (rect.area() > maxArea) {
                maxArea = rect.area();
                ixMaxArea = ix;
            }
        }

        bestRect = boundingRects.get(ixMaxArea);
    }

    return bestRect;
}

private static Bitmap findROI(Bitmap sourceBitmap) {
    Bitmap roiBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Mat sourceMat = new Mat(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), CV_8UC3);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(sourceBitmap, sourceMat);

    final Mat mat = new Mat();
    sourceMat.copyTo(mat);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Imgproc.threshold(mat, mat, 146, 250, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

    // find contours
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    List<RotatedRect> boundingRects = new ArrayList<>();
    Imgproc.findContours(mat, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // find appropriate bounding rectangles
    for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
        MatOfPoint2f areaPoints = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
        RotatedRect boundingRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(areaPoints);
        boundingRects.add(boundingRect);
    }

    RotatedRect documentRect = getBestRectByArea(boundingRects);
    if (documentRect != null) {
        Point rect_points[] = new Point[4];
        documentRect.points(rect_points);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            Imgproc.line(sourceMat, rect_points[i], rect_points[(i + 1) % 4], ROI_COLOR, ROI_WIDTH);
        }
    }
    Utils.matToBitmap(sourceMat, roiBitmap);
    return roiBitmap;
}
```

you can achieve for your source images results like this:

[image]

or that:

[image]

If you adjust threshold values and apply filters you can achieve even better results.

Comment: Appreciate your time and effort. I had already tried this solution but it does not meet my criteria actually. As you can see, the first picture's top left and right corners are a bit off. This is because of the picture is taken from an angle and not bird's eye view, making the rectangular piece of paper appear a bit like a distorted rectangle. Now if I passs on the co-ordinates of these 4 corners to the perspectiveTransformation function, the little gap will become more big, which is unacceptable for practical purposes. Can you suggest an alternative approach for the same problem?

Comment: You can use appropriate `contour`, not rect: at first - you can find best rectangle, then get contour, which bounded by that rect.

Comment: The methodology I followed was coverting to gray mat, then gaussian blur, canny, find contours, then extract the largest contour which I used to bound it whithin a Rectangle. I think you used the same methodology. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score -1):

Stop relying on edge detection, the worst methodology in the universe, and switch to some form of image segmentation.

The paper is white, the background is contrasted, this is the information that you should use.

Comment: can you suggest something specifc which helps my problem?
also, the paper background won't necessarily be white

Comment: @Gurankas: segmentation.

Comment: What kind of segmentation?

Comment: Segmentation in regions.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound dumb but can you specify any method of OpenCV which might be helpful in segmentation?

Comment: Do you mean thresholding?